# Assign class callback function to struct?

Tags: c++, class, function, pointers, callback

Recently I learn about callback function and I want to implement it in my app. Here what I have got so far.

```
// In my image.h

typedef void (__stdcall *DrawingMethod)(IplImage*, HDC, RECT*);

typedef struct _IMAGEPROCESSINGPARAMETER {
    ...
    DrawingMethod draw;
}
IMAGEPROCESSINGPARAMETER,*PIMAGEPROCESSINGPARAMETER,*LPIMAGEPROCESSINGPARAMETER;

class Image {
    public:
        void DrawOriginalSize(IplImage*, HDC, RECT*);
        void DrawToRect(IplImage*, HDC, RECT*);
        void DrawIsotropic(IplImage*, HDC, RECT*);
        int Show();
        IMAGEPROCESSINGPARAMETER ipp;
    ...
};

// In my image.cpp

int Image::Show()
{
    // Get IplImage, HDC, and RECT and finally call the function
    ...
    DrawingMethod d = ipp.draw;
    d(img, dc, &rc);
    return 0;
}

// In main.cpp

#include "image.h"
static Image img;
...
case IDC_FILE_OPEN: {
    img.ipp.draw = img.DrawOriginalSize; // This is ERROR
    img.Show();
    break;
}
```

How can I make this code to works or is it wrong to write code like this?

Thank in advance

Comment: `IMAGEPROCESSINGPARAMETER` is a beautiful name.

Comment: I'd suggest reading up on the "strategy design pattern" as this is what I think you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: Explain how it doesn't "works" at the moment and which parts you think you should change.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit * And which parts shoulds changes.

Comment: @H2CO3: That's our job.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use std::function if you are using C++11 or boost/function (if not) instead, it gives you much more representation power and is less prone to errors.

In general, it is not advisable to use such c-like techniques, if there is no compelling reason for doing so.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do more than single simple change to "fix" this.

The problem is that the member functions of `Image` (such as `DrawOriginalSize`) are not the same as regular function - they have an additional `this` parameter which is implicit, so you don't "see" that parameter. This means that a regular funciton pointer, such as `img.ipp.draw` can't be a member function.

There are a few solutions. If you make `draw` a `std::function` in `IMAGEPROCESSINGPARAMETER`, it would work straight away.

Alternatively, you will need to make the functions in `Image` static - if they still need to be member functions (That is, they are using some member variables), you will need to make a static wrapper function - the wrapper function then takes one extra parameter, which is the pointer to the object, which is then made into a `this` pointer.